# File is being used by the current executable even though using dispose function

Tags: c#, .net

Here's my code I'm trying to replace an image from one folder with another image in another folder while conserving his file name.
I'm retrieving the content of the folder using `dataGridView`
I'm loading the image from the cell selected directly to a `picturebox`
I'm using:
`File.Copy(Source, Destination,true);`
To copy my file, I made sure to dispose of EVERYTHING so it's not being used by the process.

My full project (commented):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get content of the DESTINATION files on a specific folder and put it into a dataGridView1

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\Black Desert\\FaceTexture", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("File Name");
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(files[i]);
        table.Rows.Add(file.Name);

    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

    //Get content of the SOURCE files on a specific folder and put it into a dataGridView2

    string[] files2 = Directory.GetFiles(@"Face Texture", "*");
    DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
    table2.Columns.Add("File Name");
    for (int i = 0; i < files2.Length; i++)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(files2[i]);
        table2.Rows.Add(file.Name);

    }
    dataGridView2.DataSource = table2;
}

private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string[] sizes = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
        double len = new FileInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\Black Desert\\FaceTexture\\" + dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString()).Length;
        int order = 0;
        while (len >= 1024 && order < sizes.Length - 1)
        {
            order++;
            len = len / 1024;
        }

        string result = String.Format("{0:0.##} {1}", len, sizes[order]);

        //We get the picturebox to show which file we selected in the cell (datagridview1)
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\Black Desert\\FaceTexture\\" + dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString());
        LblFileName1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
        //We have the full path here
        LblFilePath1.Text = (Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\Black Desert\\FaceTexture\\" + dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString());
        LblFileSize1.Text = result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void dataGridView2_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;

        string[] sizes = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
        double len = new FileInfo("Face Texture\\" + dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString()).Length;
        int order = 0;
        while (len >= 1024 && order < sizes.Length - 1)
        {
            order++;
            len = len / 1024;
        }

        string result = String.Format("{0:0.##} {1}", len, sizes[order]);

        //We get the picturebox to show which file we selected in the cell (datagridview2)
        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("Face Texture\\" + dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString());
        LblFileName2.Text = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
        //We have the full path here
        LblFilePath2.Text = "Face Texture\\" + dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
        LblFileSize2.Text = result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Get store into a string both paths before disposing them
        string Source = LblFilePath1.Text;
        string Destination = LblFilePath2.Text;

        pictureBox1.Dispose();
        pictureBox2.Dispose();
        dataGridView1.Dispose();
        dataGridView2.Dispose();
        LblFileName1.Dispose();
        LblFileName2.Dispose();
        LblFilePath1.Dispose();
        LblFilePath2.Dispose();
        LblFileSize1.Dispose();
        LblFileSize2.Dispose();

        File.Copy(Source, Destination, true);
        MessageBox.Show(Source + Destination);

    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {
        //Eh, used by the process ..
        MessageBox.Show(ex2.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: pictureBox1.Image.Dispose(), etc.

Comment: Hi Hans, thank you that worked.
What is the difference between `Picturebox1.Dispose();` and `Picturebox1.Image.Dispose();`

Comment: An image object created with Image.FromFile() must be disposed after use to release a lock on the file.  PictureBox can't do it for you, it doesn't know where the image came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to dispose of the image object and not the PictureBox object.

Therefore `pictureBox.Image.Dispose()` will solve the issue.

So [PictureBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-picturebox-image) has [image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property class that has a `Dispose()` method